# Por que chamar um método não está compilando?

Tags: c#, .net, método, namespace, classes

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace testando
{
    public class pessoa
    {
        public void Falar(){
            Console.WriteLine("Ola meu nome é ninguem");
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args){
            Console.WriteLine("Escreva 1 para paresentar ola na tela ou so enter para sair");
            string r = Console.ReadLine();
            if(r == "1") {
                Falar();
            }
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

Tem dois problemas: você está chamando um método em outra classe, então só pode chamá-lo usando o nome qualificado completo, portanto o nome da classe e o nome do método, a não ser que use o `using` para importar. O outro problema que eu preferi resolver assim é que esta classe e método deveriam ser estáticos, até porque eles não possuem estado, assim não precisa instanciar nada. De forma mais organizada ficaria assim:

```
using static System.Console;

namespace testando {
    class Program {
        public static void Main() {
            WriteLine("Escreva 1 para apresentar 'olá' na tela ou só <enter> para sair");
            if (ReadLine() == "1") Pessoa.Falar();
        }
    }
    public class Pessoa {
        public static void Falar() => WriteLine("Olá meu nome é ninguém");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/zpl4hD). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NlbNWs). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/CallAnotherClass.cs).

Por outro lado talvez queria só colocar o método dentro da mesma classe, aí poderia chamar o método diretamente:

```
using static System.Console;

namespace testando {
    class Program {
        public static void Main() {
            WriteLine("Escreva 1 para apresentar 'olá' na tela ou só <enter> para sair");
            if (ReadLine() == "1") Falar();
        }
        public static void Falar() => WriteLine("Olá meu nome é ninguém");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **idepne**](https://ideone.com/ZEBWA7). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mTokMP). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/CallMethod.cs).

Answer (score 3):

O método Falar, se encontra em outra classe, para que ele seja acessado através do método Main que se encontra na classe Program, a classe Pessoa deve ser instanciada e em seguida chamar o método Falar, através dela.

Segue abaixo um exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace testando
{
  public class pessoa
  {
    public void Falar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ola meu nome é ninguem");
    }
  }
  class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Escreva 1 para paresentar ola na tela ou so enter 
        para sair");
        string r = Console.ReadLine();
        if (r == "1")
        {
            pessoa pess = new pessoa();
            pess.Falar();
        }
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
  }
}
```

Uma outra solução seria definindo o método Falar como estático, assim não seria necessário instanciar a classe:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace testando
{
   public class pessoa
   {
      public static void Falar()
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Ola meu nome é ninguem");
      }
   }
   class Program
   {
      public static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Escreva 1 para paresentar ola na tela ou so enter 
            para sair");
        string r = Console.ReadLine();
        if (r == "1")
        {
            pessoa.Falar();
        }
        Console.ReadKey(true);
      }
  }
}
```